# UICollectionViewCell label is reused and placed wrongly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with a prototype cell. The cells loads and image and shows an label. As the cells have different sizes, they are changed via the CollectionViewFlowLayout. That works fine.

When I scroll the view in the Simulator, the labels seems to be reused and added wrongly on the images. How do I ensure that this do not happen and an image has only one label on the collectionview?

[image: screenshot of issue]

**UICollectionView**

```
#pragma mark - Collection view 
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    self.Data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, nil];
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.magazineLayout.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    int item = [indexPath row];

    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // Set Image
    UIImage *image;
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.png"];
    mCell.imageView.image = image; 


    // Set Label
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Image %@", self.Data[item]];
    [mCell addSubview:[self cellTitle:title indexPath:indexPath]];

    return mCell; 
}

// Title will be reused and placed wrongly on pictures !
-(UILabel *)cellTitle:(NSString *)name indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize itemSize = [self collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int top = itemSize.height - 40;
    int width = itemSize.width;

    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, top, width, 40)];
    title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    title.text = name;
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    title.alpha = 0.5f;

    return title; 
}
```

Edit: **Workaround Solution**

`viewWithTag` worked fine, but I could not reposition the label. Sadly as I think this would be the best way. Here my workaround without `viewWithTag`:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // Set Image
    UIImage *image;
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.png"];
    mCell.imageView.image = image; 

    [self cellTitleAndBackground:mCell indexPath:indexPath];

    return mCell; 
}


-(void)cellTitleAndBackground:(MagazineCell *)mCell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Get title
    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Image %@", self.Data[indexPath.row]];

    // Get current cell size
    CGSize itemSize = [self collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int top = itemSize.height - 40;
    int width = itemSize.width;

    // Create title background
    UILabel *titleBackground = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, top, width, 40)];
    titleBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleBackground.alpha = 0.2f;
    titleBackground.tag = 70;
    [self removeReusedLabel:mCell tag:70]; 
    [mCell addSubview:titleBackground];

    // Create titleLabel
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, top-8, width, 40)];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    titleLabel.text = name;
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.tag = 72;
    [self removeReusedLabel:mCell tag:72];
    [mCell addSubview:titleLabel];
}

-(void)removeReusedLabel:(MagazineCell *)mCell tag:(int)tag {
    UILabel *foundLabelBackground = (UILabel *)[mCell viewWithTag:tag];
    if (foundLabelBackground) [foundLabelBackground removeFromSuperview];
}
```

cheers -- jerik

Comment: What's your cell type: storyBoard cell, Xib or code only?

Comment: Storyboard, cofigured the cell there with imageview an label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because of cell reuse. If you're going to add the label like this, you should check to see if there is one on the cell you get from the dequeue method, and remove it if it's present. You could give the label a tag, and then use viewWithTag: to see if a label is present, and then have it call removeFromSuperview. I haven't tested this, but I think something like this should work:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *foundLabel = [mCell viewWithTag:47];
    if (foundLabel) [foundLabel removeFromSuperview];
    .......
```

Remember to set the tag of the labels to the same number when you create them in the cellTitle:indexPath method. BTW, you should be adding this label to the cell's contentView  instead of the cell itself.

**After Edit:**

This modification of your code worked fine for me, using viewWithTag:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize cellSize = [self.magazineLayout[indexPath.item] size];
    return cellSize;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RDCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    if ([mCell viewWithTag:47]) [[mCell viewWithTag:47] removeFromSuperview];
    UIImage *image = self.magazineLayout[indexPath.item];
    mCell.imageView.image = image;

    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Image %@", self.data[indexPath.item]];
    [mCell addSubview:[self cellTitle:title indexPath:indexPath]];

    return mCell;
}


-(UILabel *)cellTitle:(NSString *)name indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize itemSize = [self.magazineLayout[indexPath.item] size];
    int top = itemSize.height - 40;
    int width = itemSize.width;
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, top, width, 40)];
    title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    title.text = name;
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    title.alpha = 0.5f;
    title.tag = 47;
    return title;
}
```

In this example, the array, magazineLayout, was filled with 16 pictures of different sizes.

The easier way though, is to add the labels to your custom cell in the storyboard (or xib). If you have it pinned to the sides and bottom, and have its height set to 40, you'll get what you want with no code to create the label or check for its presence.

Comment: worked. But now i cannot change the size and position of the label. In `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` i do the following: `UILabel *titleLabel    = (UILabel *)[mCell viewWithTag:105];
[self labelPosition:titleLabel indexPath:indexPath];` and in `labelPosition` this: `CGRect position = CGRectMake(0, top, width, 40); titleLabel.frame = position;` but no effect

Comment: could not find a solution with `viewWithTag` and a repositioning of the labels. But I found another workaround, see in my initial post at **Workaround Solution**

Comment: tried again your solution. Did not work. I think its because, the reused cell, do not have always the same tags inside, if they are used. E.g. tag 47 does not exists in the reused cell, but tag 48. 48 will not be removed and therefore it is shown and I get the strange outcome. If I remove just all subviews `for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {[subview removeFromSuperview];}` it works fine.

Comment: @jerik I don't know why it didn't work for you, but if you set the tag to 47 in the storyboard, every cell will have that tag -- it will never be 48.

Comment: OK. Know I understand. I created for each cell an different tag. That was my missunderstanding. I will test it with one single (!) tag for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer has been accepted and closed. But just in case someone stumble across this thread, the right approach to avoid this problem is to subclass UICollectionViewCell and then use

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[LPCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Initialize all your elements in the initWithFrame method of the subclass

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 95.0, 106.0, 20)];
        self.lblName.text = @"";
        self.lblName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.lblName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Bold" size:10]];
        [self.lblName setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0f/255.0 green:137.0f/255.0 blue:137.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [self.lblName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self addSubview:self.lblName];
}
```

Make the elements public so that it can be accessed later in the collection view data source calls.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    LPCollectionViewCell *cell = (LPCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.lblName setText:@"This is awesome"];
}
```

And thats it!

Comment: many thanks. combining this with sizeForItemAtIndexPath worked great!